# Find the difference within a group based on a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with entries such as;

`V1 zipcode   year  V2
 1    11747   2012  5
 2    11747   2012  10
 3    11747   2012  20
 4    11747   2012  15
 1    11000   2012  20
 2    11000   2012  15
 3    11000   2012  20`

I want to find the difference in V2 for the maximum value of V1 for each zipcode year combination. In this case 15-5 and 20-20.

I would like the result to look like:

`V1 zipcode   year  V2  V3
 1    11747   2012  5    10
 2    11747   2012  10   10
 3    11747   2012  20   10
 4    11747   2012  15   10
 1    11000   2012  20    0
 2    11000   2012  15    0
 3    11000   2012  20    0`

So for I have attempting to use group by and mutate with the following conditions:
`df %>% group_by(year, zipcode) %>% mutate(difV2 = df[df$V1== max(df$V1),4] - df[df$V1== min(df$V1),4])`

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `group_by`, we need to only use the column names instead of `df$V1`.  When we do `df$V1`, it is extracting the whole column and not the values that are specific to that group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(year, zipcode) %>% 
  mutate(V3 = V2[V1== max(V1)] - V2[V1== min(V1)])
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   year, zipcode [2]
#     V1 zipcode  year    V2    V3
#  <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1   11747  2012     5    10
#2     2   11747  2012    10    10
#3     3   11747  2012    20    10
#4     4   11747  2012    15    10
#5     1   11000  2012    20     0
#6     2   11000  2012    15     0
#7     3   11000  2012    20     0
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I am however continuing to get the error: 

`Error in [[<-.data.frame(`*tmp*`, col, value = c(21849235, 4326319,  : 
  replacement has y rows, data has x`

Comment: @lnathe  The issue would be that there can be ties i.e duplicate max/min for `max` or `min` values, use `V2[which.max(v1)] - V2[which.min(V1)]`